# C# + MongoDB - ObjectId without using MongoDB DataTypes/Attributes

Tags: c#, mongodb, inversion-of-control

Using MongoDB as my data store makes me to have ObjectID type as primary key by Default. It also can be changed by using Guid with [BsonId] attribute. Which is also defined in MongoDB C# Driver library. I would like to have my Entities independent from Data layer. 
Can I just use name Id for the property to identify primary key? What else I can try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### OPTION 1:  Stick with BsonId and use the Facade Pattern

The [BsonId] property is what you'd use to indicate that the _id property should be linked to a specific property.  There isn't a way around that (short of ignoring _id entirely in your crud operations which seems like a bad idea).

So, if you want to separate your "entity" object from your "data layer" then just use a poco class.

**-- Use a [poco class](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-in-net-part-3-starting-with-poco-documents/) as a substitute for a record.**  That class is only for data storage:  a quick way to get data in/out of mongo, and a great alternative to working with bson documents.

**-- Use a facade on top of that poco class for your entity layer**.  I don't find it useful to re-invent the wheel, so I typically ask our devs have the entity interface inherit the data-layer (poco) interface, but you can do it however you'd like

### Breaking up a sample MyObject class

*IMyObjectRecord* (declared at the dal and contains only properties and mongo-specific attributes)

*IMyObject:IMyObjectRecord* (declared at the entity level and may include added properties and methods)

*MyObjectRecord:IMyObjectRecord* (declared inside the dal, contains mongo-specific attributes.  Could be declared internal if you wanted to be really strict about separation).

*MyObject:IMyObject* (could be, for example, a facade on top of the IMyObjectRecord class you pull from the dal).

Now - you get all the benefits of the facade, and you have a hard-coded link between the properties BUT, you get to keep Bson attributes contained in your dal.

### OK, fine. But I really really really HATE that answer.

Yeah.  I can accept that.  **OK, so how about a Convention Pack?**  If you ABSOLUTELY PROMISE that you'll call your Id's "Id" and you SWEAR that you'll type them as strings (or -- use some other convention that is easy to identify), then we could just use a convention pack [like the one I stole from here](https://gist.github.com/craiggwilson/5217295)

```
namespace ConsoleApp {
    class Program {

        private class Foo {
            // Look Ma!  No attributes!
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            //you would typically do this in the singleton routine you use 
            //to create your dbClient, so you only do it the one time.
            var pack = new ConventionPack();   
            pack.Add(new StringObjectIdConvention());
            ConventionRegistry.Register("MyConventions", pack, _ => true);
            // Note that we registered that before creating our client...
            var client = new MongoClient();

            //now, use that client to create collections
            var testDb = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var fooCol = testDb.GetCollection<Foo>("foo");
            fooCol.InsertOne(new Foo() { OtherProperty = "Testing", Id="TEST" });

            var foundFoo = fooCol.Find(x => x.OtherProperty == "Testing").ToList()[0];
            Console.WriteLine("foundFooId: " + foundFoo.Id);
       }

        //obviously, this belongs in that singleton namespace where
        //you're getting your db client.
        private class StringObjectIdConvention : ConventionBase, IPostProcessingConvention {
            public void PostProcess(BsonClassMap classMap) {
                var idMap = classMap.IdMemberMap;
                if (idMap != null && idMap.MemberName == "Id" && idMap.MemberType == typeof(string)) {
                    idMap.SetIdGenerator(new StringObjectIdGenerator());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### What's a Convention Pack

It's a little set of mongo "rules" that get applied during serialize/deserialize.  You register it once (when you setup your engine).  In this case, the sample pack is telling mongo "if you see a field called 'Id', then save it as a string to _id, please."

These can get really complex and fun.  I'd dig into convention packs if you really really really hate the other approach.  It's a good way to force all your mongo "attribute driven" logic into one self-contained location.

Comment: I have decided to go with: -- Use a poco class as a substitute for a record.

Comment: The convention-pack solution is the best in my opinion. There are many built-in convention packs provided by the MongoDb-Client. Why not add your own.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [BsonClassMap](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#creating-a-class-map) instead of using attributes to keep your classes "clean".

```
// 'clean' entity with no mongo attributes
public class MyClass 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

// mappings in data layer
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => 
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id).SetIdGenerator(CombGuidGenerator.Instance);
});
```

Comment: Hey Peter - that's for just the one class, right?  It would only work for MyClass?  So the OP would need to add a new classMap for every new class he adds to the data access layer.

Comment: @bri - Right, good point - this is how you would fluently map individual classes. Your suggestion of using `ConventionPack` is a good example of how to define a convention for mapping all `Id` properties.

Comment: which would u use?  just curious -- I personally like the attributes as it's clear to the entire team exactly how each poco maps to the persist. layer.

Answer (score 3):

I have stumbled on the same problem myself, and I didn't want to have mongo attributes inside my classes.

I have created a small wrapper example to show how I save and find elements without having an Id property on the data classes of my business logic.

The wrapper class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Unwrap<T>(this MongoObject<T> t)
    {
        return t.Element;
    }
}
public class MongoObject<T>
{
    [BsonId]
    private ObjectId _objectId;
    public T Element { get; }

    public MongoObject(T element)
    {
        Element = element;
        _objectId = new ObjectId();
    }
}
```

I have also added an extension method to easily unwrap.

Saving an element is simple

```
public void Save<T>(T t)
{
    _collection.InsertOne(new MongoObject<T>(t));
}
```

To find an element we can do a linq-like query:

Say we have a data class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then we can find such an element by

```
 public Person FindPersonByName(string name)
 {
     return _collection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(
               personObject => personObject.Element.Name == name).Unwrap();
 }
```

We can also generalize by making `MongoObject` implement `IQueryable<T>` and this would make the use of the wrapper even more convenient

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly. You want to put your entity to other layer without attribute.

I think you can try this

```
 public object Id { get; set; }
```

after that you can put your Id which is coming from mongodb without attribute