# Iterating mongodb collection with c# returns null

Tags: c#, mongodb

I used a suggestion in a previous [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796735/c-sharp-mongodb-objectid-without-using-mongodb-datatypes-attributes/46530333), accessing mongodb with c#.

In it the author, Belgi, essentially used a wrapper object for a POCO  with an additional ObjectId property.

From that article:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Unwrap<T>(this MongoObject<T> t)
    {
        return t.Element;
    }
}
public class MongoObject<T>
{
    [BsonId]
    private ObjectId _objectId;
    public T Element { get; }

    public MongoObject(T element)
    {
        Element = element;
        _objectId = new ObjectId();
    }
}
```

Using this wrapper, I tried to query the collection:

```
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("test");
IMongoCollection<MongoObject<MyClass>> collection = db.GetCollection<MongoObject<MyClass>>("mylist");

IMongoQueryable<MyClass> list = collection.AsQueryable().Select(t=>t.Element);
int count = list.Count();
```

The count is 5 as expected. But when I iterate over the list collection, each of the 5 members of list is null.

```
foreach (MyClass item in list)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you even got count to return anything because in this scenario I am not sure driver actually saves `T Element` into mongoDb.

I copied your code and fixed it by adding `[BsonElement]` tag above `T Element`. Like this:

```
public class MongoObject<T>
{
    [BsonId]
    private ObjectId _objectId;
    [BsonElement]
    public T Element { get; }

    public MongoObject(T element)
    {
        Element = element 
    }
}
```

This makes driver not ignore your element when saving into mongoDb. Other option is to make Element publicly settable by  `public T Element { get; set; }`, but I am not sure you want that option.

Notice how I removed `_objectId = new ObjectId();`. You don't need to do it manually, driver will do it for you.

Hope this helps. Cheers!